# Good poly-A filtering rules or tools

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-sequencing, sequence-analysis

I am aligning a large number of ESTs. It seems poly-A tails show in many different ways. In addition to occurring at the very end, they can be flanked by the cloning sequence one one end, or have mismatches/errors. What is a good rule or available tools that will handle the usual cases?

A few examples of the non-trivial cases I found, with their Genbank Accs:

```
>EE409337
... AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCTTGTC
>EE409340
... TTTCTACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACTTGTC
>EE409361
... TTGTTAAACTGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCATGTCGGC
TTACTGAATTGAA
>EE420306
.... AAAAAAAGTTATGTTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Cross-posted on [SeqAnswers](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=31628),[Biostars](http://www.biostars.org/p/76043).

Comment: Did the answer on Biostars not work for you? (If so, what is it that it *doesn't* do that you would like it to do?)

Comment: @dd3: trimest has an option for trimming the poly-A regions, but we have to specify the rules. I have already done the basic filtering, but what are the "good" rules? Is there something better than min-length and max-mismatches that will handle real sequences I have given examples of?

Comment: You could try the empirical approach. Take a random sample of N ESTs and calculate the distributions for min-length and max-mismatches. Use the distributions to pick appropriate cutoffs (some sort of statistics thing).

Comment: @dd3, that definitely makes sense and seems like a good idea. (although there's some judgement to be made for things like ...GAGAACTGGGCAAAA: where does the tail start?). Since EST processing is well established, shouldn't something like this already exist in the tools or the literature? How does everyone else do it?

Comment: I'm still a little unclear as to what you are trying to achieve that min length was failing (as you seem to be fine with trimming.  Are you wanting to trim from ACA... on 409340 and AAACTGA... on 409361 but don't want to set min-length less than 7?

Comment: @highBandWidth: that, I have no idea. I'm just getting into bioinformatics myself. sorry.

Comment: @AtlLED, I don't know what the right answer is. Min-length of 7 may be too high for some cases and low for others. Seems like max-mismatches should be high if there's a cloning palindrome at the end and low otherwise. Are there well-known settings everyone uses? Has anyone done empirical studies to see what the right conditions are?

Comment: @dd3: no, your ideas certainly help. I'm just curious as to what people have usually done.

Comment: Can you give the search criteria for the ESTs?  I have an idea for this I'd like to try.

Comment: @AtlLED, well for my purpose I am just using all the EST's for one organism from NCBI. You can just search EST's with an organism and download the results in FASTA, eg.,: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nucest?term=Brassica%20napus%5BOrganism%5D

Comment: Use dust and remove all low complexity sequences.. Or simply use a regex search to filter out poly-As